# Monitor lock in RuleBasedCollator?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Ok, so I'm trying to find out why some threaded code is bottlenecking, and looking at thread dumps, it appears that java.text.RuleBasedCollator.compare is locking a RuleBasedCollator object.

However, I look at [that code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/text/RuleBasedCollator-source.html), and there are no synchronized sections of code that could be setting this monitor lock on code. As far as I know, the only way in Java to obtain a lock is in a section of synchronized code. Below I have included the stack dump for 1) the thread that owns the lock, and 2) the thread that is waiting on it.  If you need any more info, let me know.

THREAD HOLDING THE LOCK:

```
Owns Monitor Lock on 0xc6f85460
Java Stack
at sun.text.normalizer.ReplaceableUCharacterIterator.(ReplaceableUCharacterIterator.java:44) 
at sun.text.normalizer.UCharacterIterator.getInstance(UCharacterIterator.java:66) 
at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerBase.setText(NormalizerBase.java:985) 
at java.text.CollationElementIterator.setText(CollationElementIterator.java:480) 
at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.compare(RuleBasedCollator.java:353) 
- locked [0xc6f85460] (a java.text.RuleBasedCollator) 
at java.text.Collator.compare(Collator.java:310) 
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Arrays.java:2105) 
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:2043) 
at org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.isJavaKeyword(JavaUtils.java:740)
```

THREAD AWAITING LOCK:

```
Waiting for Monitor Lock on 0xc6f85460
Java Stack
at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.compare(RuleBasedCollator.java:343) 
- waiting to lock [0xc6f85460] (a java.text.RuleBasedCollator) 
at java.text.Collator.compare(Collator.java:310) 
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Arrays.java:2105) 
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:2043) 
at org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.isJavaKeyword(JavaUtils.java:740)
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what version of Java you're using, but in Java 8, the compare method in RuleBasedCollator is synchronized:

```
public synchronized int compare(String source, String target)
```

This would explain the thread dumps you're seeing.